# pip install MySQL-python failed in linux

Tags: python, mysql, linux, django, python-3.4

I've created a Django project and its works as well now I'm trying to config it with MySql so searched in Google and did some ways but when I `pip install MySQL-python` the below problem occurs:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-lwubgejh/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/tmp/pip-build-lwubgejh/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lwubgejh/MySQL-python/
```

couldn't find any solution for this error:
`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lwubgejh/MySQL-python/`

thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library is not compatible with Python 3. Follow the [advice in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) and install mysqlclient instead.